# Three types of leaven found in the Pentateuch; what are the differences?

Tags: hebrew

Leaven appears in the Pentateuch in the following verses among others.

1. [**שְׂאֹר**](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?t=nasb&strongs=h7603) (*seh·ōre'*) found in in [Ex 12:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ex%2012%3A15&version=NASB;WLC); [12:19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ex%2012%3A19&version=NASB;WLC); [13:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ex%2013%3A7&version=NASB;WLC) (ref. [H7603](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?t=nasb&strongs=h7603))
2. [**חָמֵץ**](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?t=nasb&strongs=h2557) (*khä·māts'*) also found in [Ex 12:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ex%2012%3A15&version=NASB;WLC); [34:25](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ex%2034%3A25&version=NASB;WLC); and [Lev 6:17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Lev%206%3A17&version=NASB;WLC)<sup>1</sup> ([H2557](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?t=nasb&strongs=h2557))
3. [**מַצָּה**](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?t=nasb&strongs=H4682) (*mats·tsä'*) also found in [Ex 12:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ex%2012%3A15&version=NASB;WLC); and [Lev 10:12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Lev%2010%3A12&version=NASB;WLC) ([H4682](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?t=nasb&strongs=H4682))

All three words appear in the same verse of [Ex 12:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ex%2012%3A15&version=NASB;WLC). What are the differences between these three words for leaven and their significance in [Ex 12:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ex%2012%3A15&version=NASB;WLC)?

---

<sup>1. MT [Lev 6:10](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%95_%D7%99)</sup>

Comment: Not sure how מצה (*matzah*) can be construed as "leaven". It means.... matzah (i.e. *unleavened* bread).

Comment: yeah... the use of matzah is simply wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think these are three different words for leaven:

- שְׂאֹר is the word for "leaven" itself (i.e. yeast)
- חָמֵץ is the word used for leavened bread
- מַצָּה is the word used for unleavened bread